# Untar files containing multiple unrelated csv files programatically with Hadoop

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hive, apache-pig, tar

I have several compressed files (.tar.gz) containing unrelated tsv files (something like the list below) in my hdfs. I would like to untar those folders programmatically, potentially leveraging MPP architecture (e.g. Hadoop or Spark) and save them into hdfs.

```
- browser.tsv
- connection_type.tsv
- country.tsv
- color_depth.tsv
- javascript_version.tsv
- languages.tsv
- operating_systems.tsv
- plugins.tsv
- referrer_type.tsv
- resolution.tsv
- search_engine.tsv
```

So far I could only come up with a bash script that downloads each file from hdfs, untars and save back the folder into hdfs. I could even parallelize the script, but I am not happy with the solution either.

Thank you :)

**Edit:**

It would be interesting to see a solution done with any on the below:

- Spark 2.4.5
- Hive 2.3.6
- Pig 0.17.0
- Hadoop 2.8.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found a solution to my problem and it consists of a Mapper-only Hadoop job. Each mapper gets an uncompressed file within the tar folder and writes it to a specific path using the `MultipleOutput` utility from Hadoop.

Furthermore, I implemented a custom non-splittable Hadoop Input format to handle the Tarball extraction, called `TarballInputFormat`.

```
public class TarballInputFormat extends FileInputFormat<Text, Text> {

    @Override
    protected boolean isSplitable(JobContext context, Path filename) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public RecordReader<Text, Text> createRecordReader(InputSplit inputSplit,
                                                       TaskAttemptContext taskAttemptContext) {
        TarballRecordReader recordReader = new TarballRecordReader();
        recordReader.initialize(inputSplit, taskAttemptContext);
        return recordReader;
    }

}
```

The TarballRecordReader handles the extraction of all the files within the original tarball file.

```
public class TarballRecordReader extends RecordReader<Text, Text> {

    private static final Log log = LogFactory.getLog(TarballRecordReader.class);

    private TarInputStream tarInputStream;
    private Text key;
    private Text value;
    private boolean finished = false;
    private String folderName;

    @Override
    public void initialize(InputSplit inputSplit, TaskAttemptContext taskAttemptContext) {
        key = new Text();
        value = new Text();

        try {
            FileSplit split = (FileSplit) inputSplit;
            Configuration conf = taskAttemptContext.getConfiguration();

            Path tarballPath = split.getPath();
            folderName = tarballPath.getName().split("\\.")[0];
            FileSystem fs = tarballPath.getFileSystem(conf);
            FSDataInputStream fsInputStream = fs.open(tarballPath);

            CompressionCodecFactory compressionCodecs = new CompressionCodecFactory(conf);
            CompressionCodec codec = compressionCodecs.getCodec(tarballPath);

            tarInputStream = new TarInputStream(codec.createInputStream(fsInputStream));
        }
        catch (IOException ex) {
            log.error(ex.getMessage());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean nextKeyValue() throws IOException {

        TarEntry tarEntry = tarInputStream.getNextEntry();
        while (tarEntry != null && tarEntry.isDirectory())
            tarEntry = tarInputStream.getNextEntry();

        finished = tarEntry == null;
        if (finished) {
            return false;
        }

        key.clear();
        value.clear();

        long tarSize = tarEntry.getSize();

        int read;
        int offset = 0;
        int bufSize = (int) tarSize;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[bufSize];
        while ((read = tarInputStream.read(buffer, offset, bufSize)) != -1) offset += read;

        value.set(buffer);
        key.set(folderName + "/" + tarEntry.getName());

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public Text getCurrentKey() {
        return key;
    }

    @Override
    public Text getCurrentValue() {
        return value;
    }

    @Override
    public float getProgress() {
        return finished? 1: 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void close() throws IOException {
        if (tarInputStream != null) {
            tarInputStream.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Each tarball will be extracted keeping the original structure by writing each file relatively to its parent folder. In this solution, we have used the mapper to both read and write the extracted file all at once. This is obviously less performant but it might be a good trade-off for those who need to save their extracted files in the original form (ordered output).  An alternative approach could leverage the reducer to write each extracted file line to the file system, which should increase the write throughput at the cost of consistency (unordered files content).

```
public class ExtractTarball extends Configured implements Tool {

    public static final Log log = LogFactory.getLog(ExtractTarball.class);
    private static final String LOOKUP_OUTPUT = "lookup";

    public static class MapClass extends Mapper<Text, Text, Text, Text> {

        private MultipleOutputs<Text, Text> mos;

        @Override
        protected void map(Text key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            String filename = key.toString();

            int length = value.getBytes().length;
            System.out.printf("%s: %s%n", filename, length);

            mos.write(LOOKUP_OUTPUT, "", value, key.toString());
        }

        public void setup(Context context) {
            mos = new MultipleOutputs<>(context);
        }

        protected void cleanup(Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            mos.close();
        }
    }

    public int run(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Configuration conf = new Configuration();
        Job job = Job.getInstance(conf, "ExtractTarball");
        job.setJarByClass(this.getClass());
        job.setMapperClass(MapClass.class);

        job.setInputFormatClass(TarballInputFormat.class);
        job.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class);

        job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);

        FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));
        job.setNumReduceTasks(0);

        MultipleOutputs.addNamedOutput(job, LOOKUP_OUTPUT, TextOutputFormat.class, Text.class, Text.class);

        log.isDebugEnabled();
        return job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        int exitCode = ToolRunner.run(new ExtractTarball(), args);
        System.out.println(exitCode);
        System.exit(exitCode);
    }
}
```

This is how the output folder would look like:

```
- output
    - lookup_data
        - .browser.tsv-m-00000.crc
        - .browser_type.tsv-m-00000.crc
        - .color_depth.tsv-m-00000.crc
        - .column_headers.tsv-m-00000.crc
        - .connection_type.tsv-m-00000.crc
        - .country.tsv-m-00000.crc
        - .event.tsv-m-00000.crc
        - .javascript_version.tsv-m-00000.crc
        - .languages.tsv-m-00000.crc
        - .operating_systems.tsv-m-00000.crc
        - .plugins.tsv-m-00000.crc
        - .referrer_type.tsv-m-00000.crc
        - .resolution.tsv-m-00000.crc
        - .search_engines.tsv-m-00000.crc
        - browser.tsv-m-00000
        - browser_type.tsv-m-00000
        - color_depth.tsv-m-00000
        - column_headers.tsv-m-00000
        - connection_type.tsv-m-00000
        - country.tsv-m-00000
        - event.tsv-m-00000
        - javascript_version.tsv-m-00000
        - languages.tsv-m-00000
        - operating_systems.tsv-m-00000
        - plugins.tsv-m-00000
        - referrer_type.tsv-m-00000
        - resolution.tsv-m-00000
        - search_engines.tsv-m-00000
- ._SUCCESS.crc
- .part-m-00000.crc
- _SUCCESS
- part-m-00000
```

Answer (score 1):

Only approach I can see is iterating over each file and read with Spark for example, then with Spark itself you write it back to HDFS uncompressed. So something like this (using PySpark):

```
for p in paths
    df = spark.read.csv(p, sep=r'\t', header=True)
    df.write.csv(p, sep=r'\t', header=True)
```

**NOTE**: I haven't tested this code yet, it's complicate reproducing it in HDFS and with tar files, might be necessary to add some extra parameter to parse tar files but I hope the idea is clear.

IMHO is not possible to read all those files together in one single iteration because of the different structures they have (and different data they represent).

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Vzzarr. My goal is to untar and save back the folder on hdfs but not to process them. It will be good if you could provide a simple example of how you would do it with Spark.

Comment: Thanks, @Vzzarr. I am trying to extract those files using MapReduce. If I manage to solve it I will post the solution.